# Adding JavaScript tags dynamically - type tag receives random string of characters

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I'm dynamically adding some JavaScript tags to a page (header and footer) and each tag ends up getting injected with a random string of characters in the type field. This happens on every JavaScript tag that gets dynamically added.

For example, this tag:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXX" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Becomes this when it's dynamically added to the page:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXX" type="588dfae21373a29f8ed97bdf-text/javascript"></script>
```

This random string of characters gets added prior to text/javascript - **588dfae21373a29f8ed97bdf** - can this be avoided or prevented?

Comment: What code are you using to dynamically add the script to the page?

Comment: There's no reason to include that `type` attribute at all, JavaScript is universally the default. (There would be a reason to include `type="module"` if you were using JavaScript modules, but not if you're using non-module scripts.) So if there's an issue with that GUID-like-thing being added, you might be able to solve it by just removing `type` entirely. That said, I'd probably want to know what was adding that, and why, before I worked around it.

Comment: That was my thought as well, type isn't a necessary attribute any longer (has it ever been)? It must be an issue with the 3rd party script (gtag script in the question was just an example).